# Make a button in textarea of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible to have a button in ckeditor's textarea?

I know one could achieve this by just creating a button outside and then using css to position it to make it look like it is in the textarea, but I don't want the button go above/under txt/tables/images ... at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but there is the [Form Elements plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms) for CKEditor that lets you add various form elements to your content, including buttons. You can test it on the [Full preset demo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms). It's included in the Full preset only and you can add it to your custom build with [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).